# How do I traverse a path where I can visit the same nodes several times with a break condition of time

Tags: c#, algorithm, math, graph-theory

I need to write an algorithm that finds the optimal solution when the conditions are these:

- I have ratings of cities and the time it takes to travel between two cities (not every city has a direct road to every other city)
- The tour has to take less than 48 hours
- I have to come back to the starting city
- I need to get the highest possible sum of ratings
- And the part I am having the most trouble with: I can traverse the same city several times, but the rating of a city only sums once

I'm not sure how to approach such a problem and I failed to find anything useful so far and I only know of algorithms that traverse once. I did try a DFS and just generating every possible route as a list (this takes too long), but I'm still stuck on the condition that I can traverse a node several times, even if it is a sort of rare case.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0):

Add to your graph a "twin" for every city.  The original city has the original rating but can only be visited once.  The twin city has a rating of zero but can be visited any number of times.

The optimizing algorithm will visit the original city first because it has a finite rating, but will avoid it after the first visit ( because it is marked visited ) but will take the twin if it leads to a better results by enabling other original cities.

I suspect the case where you need to revisit a city several times would be fairly common, especially if you are travelling by air since hub and spoke arrangements are common in airline designs.

Comment: Can you add any examples of "optimizing algorithms" suitable for this problem?

Comment: @AbhinavMathur Recommend you ask your own question.  There are many variants of the travelling salesman algorithm and we can only know which to use when we have details of your particular problem.